# 'if tagged?' inside execute ressource (chef)

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

In a chef recipe I have an execute ressource where I would like the value of the command attribute to depend on whether the server is tagged in specific way (or anything else I can control from another recipe). I.e. I would like something like:

```
execute 'application_settings_control' do
    if tagged?('test-server')
      command "/usr/sbin/application_settings --disablessl --fix /etc/correct-settings.json"
    else
      command "/usr/sbin/application_settings --fix /etc/correct-settings.json"
    end
...
```

but that gives

```
NoMethodError
-----------
undefined method `tagged?' for Chef::Resource::Execute
```

It works if I put the `if tagged?...`, outside and duplicate the entire ressource definition, but that gives a lot of duplicated code, which looks bad, and is harder to maintain. I found links saying you can use `tagged?()` in `only_if`/`not_if` attributes, but that doesn't really help me (I guess I could make the code even harder to read by having two almost identical ressources with different `commands` and check the tag in `only_if`/`not_if`).

Is this just some simple syntax error I'm making or what?

Comment: Can't you do something like `command "/usr/sbin/application_settings "#{'--disablessl ' if tagged?('test-server')}--fix /etc/correct-settings.json"`. Although interpolation in that way doesn't look good.

Comment: The "'s in that is not balanced, so I might have gotten it wrong, but when I try `command "/usr/sbin/application_settings #{'--disablessl' if tagged?('test-server')} --fix...`, I get the same error as before (I'll edit that into the question, as it should be there.

Answer (score 0):

the most strightforward way is to use [node attributes](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html) in conjunection with [guards](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#guards)

```
execute 'application_settings_control' do
  command "/usr/sbin/application_settings --disablessl --fix /etc/correct-settings.json"
  only_if { node['roles'].include? 'test-server' }
end
```

you can use a [library](https://docs.chef.io/libraries.html) and implement your own `tagged?` function and use it within your recipes in conjunction with guards

alternatively, you could use regular if statement smartly

```
execute 'application_settings_control' do
  diable_ssl = node['roles'].include?('test-server') ? '--disablessl' : ''
  command(lazy { "/usr/sbin/application_settings #{disable_ssl} --fix /etc/correct-settings.json" })
end
```

Comment: But that would still mean that I had to duplicate the entire ressource?

Comment: @Henrik: i've updated my answer. hope it'll help you